# Static methods and good design

Tags: objective-c, oop, objective-c-category

I've seen a way of initialising a view controller that intrigued me. Could be my lack of experience, but I find it very useful, however, I'm trying to see if there are any reasons for which one should avoid it so I know if I should adopt it as well.

```
UIViewController* imageC = [UIViewController imageViewController];
```

Where `imageViewController` is a static method in a category:

```
+(UIViewController*) imageViewController
{
    return [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

Is this good, reliable design? I think so, but not sure. Being a static method means it lacks context, but not sure that's a problem in this case. *What are the problems you can run in on long term if you use this approach?(If any)*

Comment: If you want a convenience constructor method, make it a class method of your derived view controller class, not UIViewController.

Comment: @HotLicks Why? It returns a different instance everytime it get's called, should be OK for multiple calls? I don't get it, can you please explain?

Comment: First off, it's silly to make a category when a method on a subclass will work just as well.  Second, that way you can have an identically-named `convenienceConstructor` method for every VC class you define -- fewer names to keep in the air.  You'll discover why your scheme is poor after you've added several more view controllers.

Comment: And the method should return a value that is the class of the object created, not UIViewController.

Comment: @HotLicks I get your point. Makes perfect sense, 2 great advantages. Thanks!

Comment: @HotLicks I don't agree that `it's silly to make a category when a method on a subclass will work just as well`. Sometimes you don't need a subclass(although it will work just as well). For example, you could have a convenience constructor on `UIColor` that returns a custom color like `[UIColor turquoise]`. No need for subclassing there.

Comment: That being said `[self alloc]` would solve your second problem as well.

Comment: @ValentinRadu - But he was doing ViewControllers, and you pretty much always want to subclass those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First, there are no static methods in Objective C. There are class methods, and they, same as instance methods, do *dynamic dispatch*. They just use the class object for this.

And that leads us to the second issue: Your code always allocates an instance of `UIViewController`, even when called on a subclass. That's not expected behavior for Objective-C. `[NSMutableArray array]` returns a mutable array, even though `array` is a convenience constructor defined in `NSArray`.

The third issue is minor: It would be beneficial for users of subclasses if you would declare your method to return `instancetype`. That way your saying the method returns an instance of the receiver class and the compiler can do its static type checking. The concept is called `related return type` and was only recently introduced with clang.

Here's a better version:

```
+ (instancetype)imageViewController
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: I get your first point. However, how should I declare my method to return an `instancetype` object?

Comment: Wow, didn't knew about `instancetype`! That's absolutely awesome!

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe If you `alloc` is better practice to name your method `newImageViewController` (even in ARC) and drop the `instanceType` return type since it's implied for class methods that start with `alloc` or `new`.

Comment: @ValentinRadu Please explain why it's better to use a method of the `new` family.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe because that's what it does, it returns a **new** instance, doesn't it? Less important in ARC, but still good coding style. On top of that, if you use `new` as a prefix, the related result type is deduced by Clang, thus no need for `instancetype`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   UIViewController* imageC = [UIViewController imageViewController];
> ```

This is known as a *convenience constructor* or *factory method* and is perfectly legal and useful. BTW, it is a class method, not a static method.

A convenience constructor has two main traits:

1. it offers a more convenient syntax to instantiate a class over the standard alloc/init;
2. it returns an `autorelease` object that will be deallocated at the end of the current scope or at the end of the current autorelease pool.

> By now you have probably noticed in the class documentation that most Cocoa classes have a set of class methods that are named in the format +className.... These special class methods are called "convenience constructors," and are used to create temporary objects. What I mean by temporary is that objects returned by a convenience constructor are assumed to be autoreleased [...].

([source](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/07/27/cocoa.html?page=3))

EDIT: more details about the mechanism of convenience constructors (and in general about return references) can be found in the [Objective C ARC Reference, sec. 3.2.2](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values).

Comment: ARC does not interpret conveniant constructors as returning a weak pointer. It corectly interprets the returned object as being autoreleased.

Comment: How does ARC knows it's a convenience constructor and not a simple static method?

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe: while I understand your point, I also think that it depends on how you interpret and describe things. You could explain ARC in terms of the underlying retain/release mechanism, or you could describe ARC in terms of weak and strong ownership, which is somehow more "higher level" and close to ARC philosophy. By the way, I am not saying that one way is better than the otter, I am fine with both. In any case, I have slightly changed my wording so maybe it will be less prone to misunderstanding.

Comment: @Meda: that is the default with ARC, although you can define a convenience constructor that uses the `ns_returns_retained` attribute (which is typically the case with `alloc, init, new, copy`, etc... see also my edit.

Comment: The way you are describing it is wrong. `weak` has a precise meaning in the context of ARC, but not the meaning of being autoreleased. Also, the object would not be released when the scope ends, but when the surrounding autoreleasepool ends.

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe: I removed the reference to `weak`. Also clarified when the object is actually deallocated. By the way, would it be acceptable to you saying that the object is deallocated when a referring variable goes out of scope in case the compiler does retain/release optimisation? thanks.

Comment: Much better. But regarding your last question and since we're in language-lawyer-mode: No, usually the scope is not the defining border of lifetime. As described in "6.3 Precise Liftetime Semantics", object lifetime is subject to optimizations that reduce the pointee's lifetime even more than the pointers.

Comment: B.t.w. the last sentence of the quote "[...] and are thus valid only within the method that uses the convenience constructor." is wrong. Autoreleased objects can safely be passed back through the call chain, unless an autorelease pool is drained.